# Is it possible to null T or 'this' at the end of generic function for Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, generics

I have in my project a listener. It is assigned to `drawerLayout`. I would like to in lambda function remove it and null it at once (sequentially). Is it possible to null T or `this` at the end of generic function.

Here is my code:

```
// Usage
actionBarListener?.let {
   drawerLayout.removeDrawerListener(it) // remove listener
   actionBarListener = null // null it
}

// Usage expected
actionBarListener.releaseAndSetNull {
   drawerLayout.removeDrawerListener(it) // remove listener and null it
}

// Generic
fun <T> T?.releaseAndSetNull(block: (T?) -> Unit) = apply {
    this?.apply { block.invoke(this) }
    this = null // Error: variable expected
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Ivo Beckers said, this function would only work on `var`s, i.e. `KMutableProperty0<T>`. So you *could* write an extension on `KMutableProperty0<T?>`, and use reflection to set it, if you don't mind using reflection, that is.

```
inline fun <T: Any> KMutableProperty0<T?>.releaseAndSetNull(block: (T?) -> Unit) {
    block(this.get())
    this.set(null)
}

// or if you don't want the block to be called if the property is null:

inline fun <T: Any> KMutableProperty0<T?>.releaseAndSetNull(block: (T) -> Unit) {
    this.get()?.run(block)
    this.set(null)
}
```

Then suppose you have a property:

```
var foo: Int? = 10
```

You can do:

```
::foo.releaseAndSetNull { println("Foo: $it") }
// or if foo belongs to someObject
someObject::foo.releaseAndSetNull { println("Foo: $it") }
```

Looking at the generated bytecode, the way this is implemented (which is subject to change) is that each unique property referred to by a property reference in this way causes an inner class to be generated. The inner class will then have `get` and `set` methods that do their jobs with little extra cost - as they can just set the right property *directly*. So really the main cost is the extra inner class that is generated.

Comment: Would it to be OK if I changed this line `block(this.get())` to `this.get()?.let { block(it) }` ? I would like to receive `T` only if it is not null.

Comment: @deadfish do you want the block to be called if the property is null? If so, use `.let`, otherwise you can use `?.let`. You just *love* scope functions, don’t you? (I don’t see how this improves the readability in this case, but it’s your choice at the end of the day.)

Comment: `this.get()?.run(block)` might be more readable in my opinion. See the edit. @deadfish

Comment: Yes, it's better now, thanks. There is also a `block -> (T)`. What would happen if I used `block -> T.()`. Would it change totally the logic? It would pass the real object instead a copy, wouldn't it?

Comment: @deadfish I don’t know what you mean by “copy” or “real object”. Are there “fake” objects now? In any case, `T.() -> Unit` and `(T) -> Unit` are the same type as far as the type system is concerned. The only difference is when resolving overloads. I’ve also declared it inline, so the lambda is inlined into the call site. Nothing is actually “passed” at runtime.

Answer (score 2):

I can think of several reasons why this could never work.

First of, the generic function doesn't know if `this` is a `var` or `val`. And this functionality could only works on a `var`

Likewise, it can't know if it's nullable, that's also a requirment.

Furthermore, it can even be the case that it's not a variable that's calling the function.

Like say you have

```
fun getActionBarListener() {
    return actionBarListener
}
```

Then somewhere else you could do

```
getActionBarListener().releaseAndSetNull {
   drawerLayout.removeDrawerListener(it) // remove listener and null it
}
```

How do you expect that to work?

Or even anonymous objects could call this function.